# How to print values with similiar string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to read a large csv file and print out all the similar values, since its all about hotels and to make it simple I will make a list of dicts here for this code:

```py
S1 = [{'name': 'Holiday Inn A','price': '552'},
{'name': 'Holiday Inn B','price': '568'},
{'name': 'Holiday Inn C','price': '589'},
{'name': 'Grand Palace','price': '768'}
and so on...]
```

What I mean is that I want to print out all values with the name 'Holiday Inn' in it, this is my desired result:

```
Holiday Inn A
Holiday Inn B
Holiday Inn C
```

Here's my code:

```py
import csv

name = []
value = []
linked = []
a = []

def filereader():
    line_count = 0
    with open('hotelRev.csv','r', encoding ='utf-8') as fileIn:
        reader = csv.reader(fileIn)
        for row in reader:
            line_count = line_count + 1
            if line_count == 1:
                name.append(row)
            else:
                value.append(row)

    for x in name:
        for y in value:
            linked.append(dict(zip(x,y)))

filereader()
for row in linked:
    a.append(row['name'])

b = sorted(set(a))

for row in linked:
    print(row['name']['Holiday Inn'])
```

and clearly this isn't working so, anyone got an idea of how to do it?

edit-1: by similar I mean by classifying all Holiday Inn elements into a big group so its easier to be called out and printed.

A direct example from the dataset itself:

```
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South                             
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Baton Rouge East                         
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Bethlehem                                
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Bloomington                              
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Butte                                    
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Carmel-north Indianapolis                
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Carpinteria                              
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Columbus - Polaris Parkway               
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Columbus Univ Area - Osu                 
Holiday Inn Express & Suites Denver Northeast - Brighton
```

if possible I would love to find a way to print them out with as little lines as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic solution using sets. I think it won't be efficient for a very large dataset but it can be referred to create an efficient solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('HotelNames.csv')

search_terms = input('Enter search terms: ')
#Convert to lower case
search_terms = search_terms.lower()
#Remove special characters except space
search_terms = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', search_terms)

#Make a list of words from the string
temp = search_terms.split(' ')

search_set = set()
for i in range(len(temp)):
    #Make a set of unique words
    search_set.add(temp[i])

for i in range(len(df)):

    t = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', df.iloc[i][0])
    t = t.lower()
    temp = t.split(' ')

    hotel_set = set()
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        hotel_set.add(temp[j])

    #Find whether the searched terms are a subset of the hotel name in that particular row
    if(search_set.issubset(hotel_set)):
        print(df.iloc[i][0])
```

The `HotelNames.csv` currently contains 1 column i.e. the names of hotels.

Comment: Thanks for helping! But sadly I'm still an amaetur at coding so I dont know like alot on the code you wrote, maybe you'll be free to umm explain it a bit?

Comment: what I want to know is the panda module, re module? the .sub thingy and the iloc thingy

Comment: You'll have to search Google and learn with practice. Pandas module is used for reading data files (Eg: csv) into dataframes (Table-like structure). One of the way to access a row in a dataframe is by using 'iloc'. 
RE module is for Regular Expressions from which I've used 'sub' to remove special characters (&, -) so that there is no need to enter it in search.

You can put print statements everywhere to help for easier understanding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly try the code when I'm free! and yes I'll google as much as I could, my teacher is still teaching me those basic operators and it sucked

Answer (score 0):

I think what is missing is a firm definition of what you mean by similar. I recommend you rite a function or method that returns boolean true if two strings match your definition of similar. Once you have this worked out, the rest ought to fall into place with an if statement.

Some test strings for you to consider.. (you decide if they are similar and why)

"Holiday inn " 
"Holiday in " 
"holiday inn" 
"holiday_inn" 
" holiday inn" 
"lollyday inn" 
"^*$%__holiday inn!" 
"The San Francisco Holiday Inn and Suites" 
etc.

One thing you may wish to look at, and get familiar with is the concept of Phonetic Distance. Here is a Python library for that.. https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish

Comment: The csv file i have comes in a format where the names of the hotels have spacing in between, a direct example for this is in here, from the datafile itself:
```Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South                             Holiday Inn Express & Suites Baton Rouge East                         Holiday Inn Express & Suites Bethlehem                                Holiday Inn Express & Suites Bloomington                              
```
I want to classify all of them into one big list so its easier to print out all of them if I tagged Holiday Inn

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comments it sounds like your data is actually pretty structured (though some entries might need a little edit to clean them up).  One approach you could take is to look at groups of names with common prefixes.

I will use words instead of characters, and dict + helper functions instead of a class, to make it as straightforward as possible.

```
ITEMS_KEY = None  # Anything that isn't a string is safe here

def add_item(lookup, item):
    words = item.split()
    # e.g.: ["Holiday", "Inn", "Express", "&", "Suites", "Austin", "South"]
    for word in words:
        # Add a lower level lookup if needed
        lookup = lookup.setdefault(word, {})
        # Making this word.lower() makes searches case-insensitive
    lookup.setdefault(ITEMS_KEY, set()).add(item)  # Add the full item
    # e.g.:
    # lookup = {"Holiday": {"Inn": {"Express": ... {"South: {None: set(["Holiday Inn Express ..."]}}

def get_items_matching_prefix(lookup, prefix):
    # Simple version with full words only
    # Find the tree of results
    words = prefix.split()
    for word in words:
        lookup = lookup.get(word, {})
    return all_values(lookup)


def all_values(lookup):
    # Collect all the results
    ret = set()
    for k, v in lookup.iteritems():
        if k == ITEMS_KEY:
            ret.update(v)
        else:
            ret.update(all_values(v))
    return ret


csv_data = [
    "Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South",
    "Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin North",
    "Holiday Inn Oriental Express",
]

lookup = {}  # Could be a class or recursive collections.defaultdict
for row in csv_data:
    # e.g. row = "Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South"
    add_item(lookup, row)

print get_items_matching_prefix(lookup, "Holiday Inn")
# set(['Holiday Inn Oriental Express', 'Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin North', 'Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South'])
print get_items_matching_prefix(lookup, "Holiday Inn Express")
# set(['Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin North', 'Holiday Inn Express & Suites Austin South'])
```

A more advanced technique might be to try to search for a set of common substrings, decide those are hotels, and parse your csv into Hotel + metadata, add some chain -> hotel maps, and use that richer data instead.